# Type Error: Cannot read the property of "send" of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

Sorry for a lot of question today. I am working on my ticket command but got this error Type Error: Cannot read the property of "send" of undefined

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Any form of help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
bot.on("message", message =>{
    const args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ")
    if(message.author.bot) return
    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return
    if(message.content.startsWith(`${PREFIX}openticket`)){
        const reason = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
        const role2 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role2 => role2.name == "@everyone");

        

    message.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${message.author.username}`,  {
        permissionOverwrites: [
            {
              id: role2.id,
              deny: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
              deny: 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY',
              deny: 'SEND_MESSAGES'
            }, {
              id: message.author.id,
              allow: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
              allow: 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY',
              allow: 'SEND_MESSAGES'
            }
          ]

    })

        const embedcreated = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#f00202")
        .setDescription(`You ticket has been created ` + `#ticket-${message.author.username}` )
        .setTitle("Tickets")
        .setFooter(`Tickets System`)
        .setTimestamp()

        message.channel.send(embedcreated);
        const embedticket = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#f00202")
        .addField(`Hey ${message.author.username}!`, ` Please wait until support arrives`)
        .setTimestamp();

        const ticketchannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(channel => channel.name == `ticket-${message.author.username}`)
            ticketchannel.send(embedticket),
            ticketchannel.send(`${message.author}`)
        }})
```

The error is in here: `ticketchannel.send`

I tried `` let ticketchannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(channel => channel.name == `ticket-${message.author.username}`) ``

And putting the code in different places but still doesn't work

Comment: well the error means that `ticketchannel` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are execting some object from `message.guild.channels.cache` that should have a `send` method. Two things that can happen over here -

1. `channel.name == ticket-${message.author.username}` this condition is not being fulfilled by anything present inside `message.guild.channels.cache`.
2. Whatever object you are getting from `message.guild.channels.cache.get` does not have the `send` method.

`let` and `const` do not have anything to do with the value. They are replaceable unless you are reassigning the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to fetch the channel in a variable, just use a callback. Also, the `allow` and `deny` properties allow `arrays`, so you can combine all permission flags to an `array`

```js
message.guild.channels
 .create(`ticket-${message.author.username}`, {
  permissionOverwrites: [
   {
    id: role2.id,
    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
   },
   {
    id: message.author.id,
    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
   },
  ],
 })
 .then((channel) => {  // pass the `channel` parameter in the callback

  // ...

  channel.send(embedticket);
  channel.send(`${message.author}`);
 });
```